# Too many redirects error after defining a redirect in Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have an ASP.NET MVC (5) application and need to redirect urls such as

`<domain>/london` to `<domain>/locations/london`

I've defined a redirect in Web.config in `system.Webserver`

```
<rule name="london">
     <match url="london" />
     <action type="Redirect" url="locations/london" />
</rule>
```

When I run the site locally and browse to `localhost:1111/london` I get the following error

> localhost redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

What am I doing wrong?

I've spent some time looking online but can't find the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your rule is basically saying if the URL contains `London` then redirect to `locations/London`. But `locations/London` contains the word `London` too so it will redirect again.

Try setting the rule to be

```
^london
```

(start with london)